# How to convert list column into a single column and the concat in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like convert each list column into one single column and then concat for below dataframe

```
 data = {'labels': ['[management,workload,credibility]','[ethic,hardworking,profession]'],
    'Score': [[0.55,0.36,0.75],[0.41,0.23,0.14]]}
 # Create DataFrame
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

new dataframe output should look like this

```
    labels         Score
    management      0.55
    workload        0.36    
    credibility     0.75
    ethic           0.41
    hardworking     0.23
    profession      0.14
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create lists from `labels` column by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(labels= df['labels'].str.strip('[]').str.split(','))
         .explode(['labels','Score']))
```

For oldier pandas versions use:

```
df1 = (df.assign(labels= df['labels'].str.strip('[]').str.split(','))
         .apply(lambda x: x.explode()))
print (df1)
        labels Score
0   management  0.55
0     workload  0.36
0  credibility  0.75
1        ethic  0.41
1  hardworking  0.23
1   profession  0.14
```

Comment: I got an error ValueError: column must be a scalar . Thank you